# Default API Route not working even without ODATA

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am running into a problem when I call /api/something/67545217-0fed-4058-9cfc-f6363412f5a2. It calls the get all. The other Get's work, but I think it is because they use the {action} in the url. And I am using the [ActionName] decorator.

Here is my routing:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // enable CORS
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new ControllerSelector(config));

        // enable OData Queries
        // http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options
        config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Survey>("Survey");

        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi", 
            "api/{controller}/{actionuniqueid}", 
            new 
            { 
                actionuniqueid =
                    @"^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$"
            });

        // Match All Regular Get Calls
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultController", "api/{controller}");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiActionId",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{actionuniqueid}",
            null,
            new
            {
                action = @"^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$",
                actionuniqueid =
                    @"^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$"
            });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiTwoActionId",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{actionuniqueid}/{actionsecondaryid}",
            null,
            new
            {
                action = @"^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$",
                actionuniqueid =
                    @"^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$",
                actionsecondaryid =
                    @"^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$"
            });
    }
```

Here are all my gets...when I call the controller, with only the ID...the correct path is not being called. Is it because it has the same setup as by type?

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Test))]
    public IQueryable<Test> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        IEnumerable<Test> test= (new Test()).PullList<Test>(LoadDepth.Self, "ByAll");
        IQueryable results = test.AsQueryable();
        return opts.ApplyTo(results) as IQueryable<Test>;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable]
    [ActionName("ById")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Test))]

    public IQueryable<Test> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts, Guid actionuniqueid)
    {
        IEnumerable<Test> test = (new Test()).PullList<Survey>(
                LoadDepth.Everything, 
                "ById",
                actionuniqueid);
        IQueryable results = test.AsQueryable();
        return opts.ApplyTo(results) as IQueryable<Test>;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ByType")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Test))]
    public IQueryable<Test> GetByType(ODataQueryOptions opts, Guid actionuniqueid)
    {
        IEnumerable<Test> survey = (new Test()).PullList<Survey>(
            LoadDepth.Everything,
            "ByType",
            actionuniqueid);
        IQueryable results = test.AsQueryable();
           return opts.ApplyTo(results) as IQueryable<Test>;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### install nuget package for odata

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData"
```

### Add following code in your "WebApiConfig.cs" file

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ViewTest>("TestOdata");
var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "odata", model: model);
```

### Add following code in your "UsersOdataController.cs" file

```
public class TestOdataController : OdataController
    {
        //GET odata/TestOdata       
        public IQueryable<ViewTest> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return context.View_TestRepository.GetQueryable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw ex;               
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewTest : view model class with your required columns
View_TestRepository : Repository class

you can access your web api by following URL:

```
"http://localhost:8080/odata/TestOdata"
```

Comment: I am already doing all of this stuff. There is just one 'Get' that isn't working.

Comment: See above, I added more code. Is it because the ByType and ByID has the same parameters? How can I route to the ByID, when not used.

Comment: Use OData routing conventions. refer this one "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions"

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do the following, added the action route:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi", 
            "api/{controller}/{actionuniqueid}", 
            new 
            { 
                actionuniqueid =
                    @"^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$|({|\()?[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}(}|\))?$|^({)?[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,10}(, {0,1}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}){2}, {0,1}({)([0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}, {0,1}){7}[0xA-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}(}})$",
                Action = "ById"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still use v3 or have moved up to v4, but if you still utilize Web API, the

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
```

needs to be before the Odata Routing